# Asynchronous function call with status variable on NodeJS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, asynchronous

I'm writing a REST client to access a REST server that paginates the replies. I've written something like the below, using Node's HTTPS library:

```
var nextPage = true, pageNo=0;

do {
  // builds the url
  options.path = "?page=" + pageNo;

  var req = HTTPS.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      parser(chunk, function(err, result) {
        // do something with result
        if (!("nextPage" in result)) {
          nextPage = false;
        }
      });
    });
  });
  // handle errors and end request

  pageNo++;

} while(nextPage)
```

This of course doesn't work, because the request to the server is handled asynchronously and the nextPage variable is never updated, but I can't figure out a way to make it work using higher-order functions.

Should I wrap the request around a recursive function, passing the state every time?  Or is there a better way?

UPDATE 1: 
Do you mean something like this?

```
var nextPage = true, pageNo=0;
var async = require('async');

async.doWhilst ( function () {
  // builds the url
  options.path = "?page=" + pageNo;

  var req = HTTPS.request(options, function(res) {...});

  // handle errors and end request

  pageNo++;

}, function () {return nextPage;}, function () {});
```

It does not work either, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`async.doWhilst()`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async#doWhilst) would an equivalent asynchronous-capable iterator. For future reference, you'll also want to look into [Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Comment: In what way would you expect your pagination to work? I would recommend you return a continuation token to the client which they can include in the API call and have the server make sense of it and return the relevant results - rather than trying to perform the pagination in one continuous request.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. I cannot change the server API: it returns a list of resources in xml and the results are paginated, with a _nextPage_ attribute if there are more. I do not know the number of results or the number of pages beforehand, I just have to keep asking until the pages are finished.